# Data-toggle doesn't work on Twitter Bootstrap 2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to set up tabs on the upper part of "mypage" and wrote the code as below in line with guidance but it doesn't work. I have no idea why it doesn't. Could you tell me why?

There may be something wrong around data-toggles.

```
<div class="span8">
      <ul class= "nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab">疑問リスト</a></li>
       <li><a href="#menu2" data-toggle="tab">フォロー中の投稿</a></li>
       <li><a href="#menu3" data-toggle="tab">ユーザーの投稿</a></li>  
      </ul> 
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="menu1">
          <h4 class="title">疑問リスト </h4>
           <div class="message_area">
             <% @posts_in_groups = GroupMessage.where(:member_id => params[:id]).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3) %>
               <% @posts_in_groups.each do |post| %>  
                <div class="each_message">
                  <%= link_to post.group do %>
                    <%= image_tag post.group.imageurl, :width => '20', :height => '25' %>
                    <%= "(" + post.group.name + ")" %>
                  <% end %>
                  Page: <%= post.page %> &
                  Line: <%= post.line %>
                  (<%= post.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                  <div class="group_message">
                    <p class="message_content">
                      <%= link_to truncate(post.content, :length => 50), post %>
                    </p>
                  </div><!--group_message-->
                  <br>      
                </div><!--each message-- >   
                <%= will_paginate(@posts_in_groups) %> 
              <% end %>  
            </div><!--message area-->
          </div><!--menu1-->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu2"> 
          <h4 class="title">フォロー中の投稿 </h4>
           <div class="message_area">
              <% @member=Member.find(params[:id])%>
              <% follwers = @member.friends.reverse.map{ |f| f.friend_id }%>
              <% join_groups = @member.groups.reverse.map{ |group| group.id } %>
              <% GroupMessage.where(:group_id => join_groups, :member_id => follwers).order("created_at desc").limit(15).each do |gmsg| %> 
                <div class="each_message">
                  <a href="/groups/<%= gmsg.group.id%>" ><%= image_tag gmsg.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + gmsg.group.name + ")" %></a>
                    <%= 'Page:' + gmsg.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + gmsg.line.to_s %>
                  <a href="/members/<%= gmsg.member.id%>"><%= gmsg.member.name %></a>
                  (<%= gmsg.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                 <div class="group_message">  
                  <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= gmsg.id%>" > <%= truncate(gmsg.content, { :length => 50}) %></a></p>
                 </div><!--group_message-->
                 <br/>
                  <% if gmsg.group_message_comments.present? %>
                     <% gmsg.group_message_comments.each do |gmsc|%>
                      <div class="group_message_comment">
                         <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                         <%= gmsc.content %> 
                      </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                      <br/>
                     <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                  <% else %> 
                  <% end %> <!--if -->
                </div><!--each_message-->
                <br>
              <% end %>  <!--each do -->
           </div> <!--message_are--> 
        </div><!--menu2--> 
         <div class="tab-pane" id="menu3">
          <h4 class="title">ユーザーの投稿</h4>
            <div class="message_area">
              <% @member=Member.find(params[:id])%>
              <% join_groups = @member.group_in_members.reverse.map{ |g| g.group_id }%>
              <% join_groups = @member.groups.reverse.map{ |group| group.id } %>
              <% @gmsg_users = GroupMessage.where(:group_id => join_groups).order("created_at desc").limit(15)%>
              <% @gmsg_users.each do |gmsg| %> 
                <div class="each_message">
                  <a href="/groups/<%= gmsg.group.id%>" ><%= image_tag gmsg.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + gmsg.group.name + ")" %></a>
                    <%= 'Page:' + gmsg.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + gmsg.line.to_s %>
                  <a href="/members/<%= gmsg.member.id%>"><%= gmsg.member.name %></a>
                  (<%= gmsg.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                 <div class="group_message">  
                  <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= gmsg.id%>" > <%= truncate(gmsg.content, { :length => 50}) %></a></p>
                 </div><!--group_message-->
                 <br/>
                  <% if gmsg.group_message_comments.present? %>
                     <% gmsg.group_message_comments.each do |gmsc|%>
                      <div class="group_message_comment">
                         <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                         <%= gmsc.content %> 
                      </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                      <br/>
                     <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                  <% else %> 
                  <% end %> <!--if -->
                </div><!--each_message-->
                <br>
              <% end %>  <!--each do -->
           </div> <!--message_are--> 
        </div><!--menu3-->
      </div><!--tab-content-->
  </div><!-- span8 -->
 </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the "fade in" class in your tab content menu's. 
I created this example:
http://bootply.com/99314

You can see the "tab-pane fade" class makes th div not visible but "tab-pane fade active in" makes it appear. "active in" class is added when you select it from upper nav.

If it doesn't solve your problem, please be specific about how it is not working.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.Gokhan. I removed "</div><!--menu1-->" and it suddenly worked properly. I don't know why. Anyways,thank you for your letting me know "fade". It is cool!!